# Cannot parse this sentense

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis

I cannot determine what does this mean and what the sentence members the words are.

> A highway wide that slopes ahead.

Is "highway" an adjective here? Is "wide" a substantive? Why is "that" here?

It comes from a poem:

```
Throughout that day the rivals traveled
By Dneper's bank a common trail,
Till shades of night from orient leveled
The sloping banks and filled the vale;
Deep Dneper lies in mist; the horses
Must need be rested now and fed.
A highway wide that slopes ahead.
"Here it is time to part," they voted,
"And chance the fated aftermath."
Each changer then, by steel ingoaded,
In freedom chose its random path.
```

Comment: It seems wrong. Where does it come from?

Comment: @deadrat it comes from a poem. See the modified question.

Comment: @deadrat maybe it should be "then" instead of "that"?

Comment: Please link the poem and state who wrote it. It seems that the poem was written by a Russian and then translated to English. Is it right?

Comment: *The Dneiper River is covered in mist. It is a wide highway that rolls away ahead into the distance.*  The order of the noun (*highway*) and its attributive adjective (*wide*) are inverted for poetical purposes (likely meter).

Comment: [Criticism, discussion, and analysis of English literature](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is off-topic here.

Comment: Basically, in poetical (and other high-flown) English efflorescences, the artiste may arbitrarily switch the normal order between a noun and its modifying adjective—which is how we get locutions such as "[river deep, mountain high](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uj0wPrN_Y_4)." That appears to be what's going on with "A highway wide" in your example.

Comment: "A highway **,** wide **,** that slopes ahead."

Comment: Off-topic as this probably is, it might be useful for you to look at other translations. I don't know Pushkin's original and I don't speak or read Russian, but having glanced at both of the first two results of a google search, they both seem better translations than this. The version you have manages to miss out that another path crosses the steep highway, which is essential to understanding how the rivals can all go in different directions...  https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=ruslan+and+ludmila+translation

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is about what appears to be an error in a poor translation of a Russian poem (Alexander Pushkin's *Ruslan and Ludmila*), rather than an actual aspect of the English language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poetry often does not follow standard grammar rules. Poets often break the rules to get a desired rhyme or rhythm or tone. Do not try to learn English grammar by reading poetry or listening to song lyrics.

In this case, the sentence breaks several conventional rules.

A highway wide that slopes ahead.

"Highway" is a noun and the subject of the sentence. "Wide" is an adjective modifying "highway". Normally in English we put adjectives in front of the nouns they modify, but the poet has broken this rule.

This is not even a sentence, as it contains no predicate. We have the subject, "highway", which is modified by a subordinate clause, "that slopes ahead". And .. that's it. There's no verb outside the subordinate clause.

I think the "plain English" version of this would be, "A wide highway slopes ahead." That is, there is a highway, the highway is wide, and at some point in front of us the highway slopes upwards. The poet rearranged the words a little to fit the rhythm of the poem.

Comment: Can it be a typo? For instance, what if it were "there" or "then" rather than "that"?

Comment: Also, why the article is "a" if it relates to the highway, given it was already mentioned as "common trail"?

Comment: It's impossible to rule out entirely that it's a typo, but there's no need to think that it is. The sentence (if we accept that sentences do not need matrix verbs to be sentences, which not everyone does) sounds perfectly natural and idiomatic as poetic language. There is no grammar broken anywhere: postpositive adjectives are simply a stylistic tool often employed in poetry, and there's no rule that says that utterances without main verbs aren't allowed. I disagree with Jay’s ‘plain English’ version, though; I'd say it should be, “[The common trail is] a wide highway that slopes ahead”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Surely the grammar is broken, even adjusting the word order you get 'A wide highway that slopes ahead.' As a sentence (which isn't an answer to 'what's that?', asked while pointing at a wide sloping highway in front) it leaves me floundering... what *about* the highway? It begs a second clause, which other translations reveal to be about the other path that crosses it.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I was reading it as the travellers are on a "common trail" and then see a "highway wide", though it certainly could be read that the two are the same as you say.

Comment: @anixx Even if the "common trail" and the "highway wide" are the same, if as JanusBahsJacquet says you read this as "the common trail is a wide highway", you still need the indefinite article "a" because you have not mentioned the highway before. Yes, you've mentioned the trail and you're saying they're the same thing, but GRAMMATICALLY, as opposed to PHYSICALLY, you have not mentioned the highway before. Like if I said, "My brother is a tall man", just trying to say that my brother is tall, I would say "a tall man" and not "the tall man" because I have not previously mentioned any tall man.

Comment: ... If you had just said, "I saw a tall man enter your house yesterday", and I wanted to say that that person was my brother, I might say, "Oh, my brother is the tall man", meaning, my brother is the tall man that you just referred to.

Comment: @Spagirl Grammar doesn’t require everything to be complete sentences. That’s semantics, which is a whole ’nother kettle of fish. In the context of this poem, this noun phrase standing on its own like this makes perfect sense.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Whether all utterances are "required" to be complete sentences is probably a pointless argument. Required by whom? What are the penalties for non-compliance? But the point is, it's not a complete sentence, and thus, as Spagirl says, leaves the dangling thought, What about the highway?

Comment: @Jay I meant quite literally ‘required by grammar’; that is, ‘required in order to be grammatical’. Traditional sentences must be complete in order to be grammatical, and that goes for clauses and constituent phrases too—but there’s no requirement that everything must be traditional sentences. A noun phrase can function as a complete utterance grammatically (otherwise examples like “What’s that?” — “A highway.” would be ungrammatical, and they’re clearly not); but they must be complete. “A highway” is a grammatical utterance, and so is “a highway that slopes”—but “A highway that” is not.